# How to set CPLEX parameter in the new version of JuMP?

Tags: parameters, julia, cplex, julia-jump

In the previous version of JuMP, I was setting CPLEX parameters using the following syntax:

```
# Create a model and limit its resolution time to 600s
m = Model(solver=CplexSolver(CPX_PARAM_TILIM=600))
```

In the new version of JuMP, the syntax to create a model is:

```
m = Model(with_optimizer(CPLEX.Optimizer))
```

but I don't know how to fix the parameters.

Do you know the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
m = Model(with_optimizer(CPLEX.Optimizer, CPX_PARAM_TILIM=600))
```